# What to do when a user says it posts comments as answer, but the actual context can be treated as (looks like) an answer?

Tags: discussion, not-an-answer

As we know, if a user posts comments as answers, we can flag it as NAA.

But how about if a users mentioned the intent of posting answers is just because lacking reputation to post comments, but the "comment" is potentially (looks like) an answer like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33238820) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33822022/5263291) ?

Should we justify if the context can be an answer? Flag it NAA just for its intention even it can be an answer? Remove messages about posting comments as answers? Or no actions required?

Comment: The first example **is** an answer (and was accepted by the OP). It could be tidied up a bit though to make it clearly an answer. I won't do that (as it would not fit your question). The second example could be flagged "in need of moderator intervention" > "Please convert to a comment".